# Opening contact list on button press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

. I am building a mobile application in react native .I need to see the contact list on my phone after clicking a button in the header in a screen , Can anyone suggest me some solutions

Comment: https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts try this package but u'll have some issues while using ios because they maintain privacy

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/LynxITDigital/react-native-contacts-wrapper